# Remove property from Json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have one collection of json objects as follows.

```
[
  {"FirstName":"Test1","LastName":"User","Email":"test@test.com","City":"ahmedabad","State":"sk","Country":"canada","Status":"False","iUserID":"23"},
  {"FirstName":"user","LastName":"user","Email":"u@u.com","City":"ahmedabad","State":"Gujarat","Country":"India","Status":"True","iUserID":"41"},
  {"FirstName":"Ropbert","LastName":"Jones","Email":"Robert@gmail.com","City":"NewYork","State":"gfg","Country":"fgdfgdfg","Status":"True","iUserID":"48"},
  {"FirstName":"hitesh","LastName":"prajapti","Email":"h.prajapati@zzz.com","City":"","State":"","Country":"","Status":"True","iUserID":"78"}
  ]
```

Now I want to remove some properties (eg. Email & city ) from all this objects without using loop. can somebody guide me How to do this in a better way in javascript?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator and [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this

```
objects.forEach(function(currentItem) {
    delete currentItem["Email"];
});
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to use a loop :)

Comment: @Andy, OP may not even want to see the word "for" in the code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to remove the properties from the JSON string:

```
s = s.replace(/,"Email":"(\\"|[^"])*","City":"(\\"[^"])*"/, '');
```